# error al actualizar registro desde un spinner

Tags: php, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola  lo que  quiero es que  por medio de  un spinner seleccionar la familia que deseo  modificar localizándolo por medio de  un id, al  mismo  tiempo  introducir la modificación en un campo en  blanco.

**Este es mi código PHP.**

```
     <?php
     require('conexion.php');

     $id=$_POST['id'];
     // Consulta de Usuarios en la base de  datos
        $consulta = "SELECT *
                             FROM tb_familia
                             WHERE id = ?";
          $comando=$conn->prepare($consulta);
          $comando->execute(array($id));
          $row=$comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($row)
          {
       $id=$_POST['id'];
       $familia=$_POST['familia'];

      // Creando consulta UPDATE
        $consulta = "UPDATE tb_familia" .
            " SET familia=? " .
            "WHERE id=?";

        // Preparar la sentencia
        $cmd = $conn->prepare($consulta);

        // Relacionar y ejecutar la sentencia
        $cmd->execute(array($familia,$id));

        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '1',
                'mensaje' => 'Se actualizó  correctamente en familia')
        );
}
else
{
    // Código de  error
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '2',
                'mensaje' => 'No se actualizó  por que  no hay una familia  con este ID')
        );
}

?>
```

**Este  es mi código  Java(Android)**

// ACTUALIZAR FAMILIA

```
    private void submitForm() {
    ActualizarFamilia(
            String.valueOf(spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItemId()),
            etmodificacion.getText().toString());
}

private void ActualizarFamilia(final String id, final String familia) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";
    showLoadingDialog("Espere Actualizando ......");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_UPDATE_FAMILIA, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado = jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this," Actualización  en Productos  con  éxito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast1.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);;
                    toast1.show();
                    Limpiar();
                } else {
                    hideLoadingDialog();
                    Toast toast2= Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this,"No se Actualizó  por que no existe un  Producto con este código",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast2.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                    Limpiar();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast toast3=  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            toast3.show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id",id);
            params.put("familia", familia);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}


public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(texto);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }

}

public void hideLoadingDialog() {
    try {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception a) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

//CODIGO PARA  MOSTRAR  LOS DATOS EN  EL  SPINNER
//SPINNERT  TIPO FAMILIA

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i < familiasList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(familiasList.get(i).getFamilia());
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);


    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spbuscarfamilia.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}

private void SeleccionaItemFamilia(Spinner spbuscarfamilia, String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spbuscarfamilia.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spbuscarfamilia.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            spbuscarfamilia.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

private class Getfamilia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = new ProgressDialog(updateFamilia.this);
        loading.setMessage("Obtencion del tipo de Usuario..");
        loading.setCancelable(false);
        loading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(Config.URL_SP_FAMILIA, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray frutas = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("familia");

                    for (int i = 0; i < frutas.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) frutas.get(i);
                        Familia cat = new Familia(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                catObj.getString("familia"));
                        familiasList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "¿No ha recibido ningún dato desde el servidor!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (loading.isShowing())
            loading.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }

}
```

// CODIGO  PARA  POBLARLO

```
    spbuscarfamilia=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spbuscafamilia);
    familiasList = new ArrayList<Familia>();

    // seleccionar las frutas del spinner
    spbuscarfamilia.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    new Getfamilia().execute();
```

Comment: Pero cual es el error?

Comment: @Jorgesys no me  actualiza, me  dice que no encontró  la  familia  que deseo actualizar

Comment: Hola @Sofia (Sofi) regularmente este tipo de problemas no son de la aplicación Android, en realidad son de la consulta, en este caso el .PHP, revisa primeramente si al cambiar tu consulta obtienes los datos esperados.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys  buen día, ya  me  actualiza con el código que  te muestro, sólo que  si yo quiero actualizar un  registro con el Id 5 me actualiza el Id 4. ¿Podrías  ayudarme?..Añadí  esto en submitForm(  ){ ActualizarFamilia( String.valueOf(spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItemId()),) }

Comment: @Sofia como defines setSelectedItemId() agrega esa parte del código.

Comment: @Jorgesys este es todo  mi código para actualizar, mi problema  es precisamente ese, se que  getSelectedItemId  es la que  me permite  obtener  el Id de mi  spinner   para  posteriormente  eliminarlo  de mi bd.No  se  como  declararlo. ¿agradeceré  muchísimo   tu ayuda?

Comment: @David quiero actualizar por  id, por ejemplo  el Id 5 de mi espinner le  doy actualizar y el id  que  me actualiza es el 4, no el que yo selecciono

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo con el que llenas tu spinner?

Comment: @David acabo  de agregar  a  mi  código  como  lleno mi spiner. De  antemano  agradezco tú  ayuda.

Comment: @Jorgesys acabo de  agregar todo el código para  hacer funcionar  mi actualización  utilizando el Spienner, espero  y puedas ayudarme a  localizar   mi error.

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener los datos del elemento que seleccionas, en este caso usa el método `onItemSelected()` y usa la variable `position`, por cierto `SeleccionaItemFamilia()` no le veo utilidad, además no muestras quien lo llama:

```
/*private void SeleccionaItemFamilia(Spinner spbuscarfamilia, String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spbuscarfamilia.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spbuscarfamilia.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            spbuscarfamilia.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Define elemento seleccionado.
                spbuscarfamilia.setSelection(position);
}
```

Comment: disculpa por molestarte  tanto, ya  agregué el código que  me  comentaste  pero  me  marca error en esta  parte. private void submitForm() {
    ActualizarFamilia(
            String.valueOf(spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItemId()),
            etmodificacion.getText().toString());
} ,  ya  intente  ponerlo de  esta  manera  spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItem().toString(),  pero me  marca  error, me  dice  que  no encuentra el Id  que  estoy buscando.

Comment: este código me  servirá  para obtener los  items por  id de  mi aplicación? No   logro solucionarlo.    mySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(mySpinner, myValue));

 //private method of your class
 private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString)
 {
  int index = 0;

  for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
   if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)){
    index = i;
    break;
   }
  }
  return index;
 }

Comment: me  puedes  ayudar  por favor?  ya  revisé todo  mi código y mostrarlo  en el text  el valor que  voy a  actualizar  y todo bien. Esta es  la parte  donde  creo que  tengo el error.   private void submitForm() {
    ActualizarFamilia(
            String.valueOf(spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItemId()),
            etmodificacion.getText().toString());
}